# Error of Simpson's Rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule, mean-value-theorem

How do I show that
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx - I_1 = - \frac{h^5}{90}f^{(4)} (\xi)$$
with $\xi \in [a,b]$ and
$$I_1 := \frac{h}{3}(f(a) + 4f\left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right) + f(b))$$
and $h= \frac{b-a}{2}$.
I was thinking about about the mean value theorem somewhere, but I am not sure how to apply it to get to the result.

Comment: I think what you do is pick up a good Calculus textbook, and see how it's proved there. Also, you could look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/prove-simpsons-rule-including-error-using-the-integral-remainder or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732738/numerical-integration-error-for-simpsons-rule-through-taylor-series

Comment: You can go via the Taylor expansion in the midpoint, or using the mean value theorem like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768667. Adding sufficient detail, both amount to the same in the end, only the contributing theoretical parts are grouped differently.

Comment: Süli and Mayers "An Introduction to Numerical Analysis" (Cambridge University Press, 2003) discuss this in chapter 4. No, it isn't a simple calculus exercise.